# FTP alternative to work on a shared file

Tags: ftp

I would like to know different options or alternatives to ftp server, in order to share a file between a java application and an admin, who can edit that file.

The file is just a list, which can be modified by the admin, and it will be read by a CSV parser already implemented:

```
 String strFile = "C:\\localPath\\stopphrases.csv";

            //create BufferedReader to read csv file
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new FileReader(strFile));
            String strLine = "";
            StringTokenizer st = null;

            while( (strLine = br.readLine()) != null){
                st = new StringTokenizer(strLine, ";");
            }
```

The only idea I have is a ftp server, but I am sure there are other possibilities that I don´t know. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how much you want to change in the client. But maybe a cloud service like DropBox or Google drive could work? That way you set up a local folder that is automatically synked to the "Admin" who can change it and it will be synced back.

This solution would mean that you might have to change your code, and if so the path would be the only change.

Comment: Yes, I have to change my code. I would like to find an easy way to connect to the java application without downloading the file and other odd steps. Thanks for your ideas, I´ll check them out

Comment: If it is a valid solution for your environment I think it's less work than using an FTP. But it all comes down to if you can use a cloud service in your project or not. Good luck!